# Generate single-dimensional array with MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

I have a simple 2 column table with the fields `id` and `entry`.

I want to select only the entries:

`SELECT entry FROM table`

However this query generates a multi dimensional array. I need to generate a simple, single-dimensional array. I know I could possibly do this after in my Phyhon code but the database is very large (100,000+ columns) and I'd like to not have to go through this extra step before I can exploit my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack the result as follow:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT entry FROM table')
rows = [entry for entry, in cursor.fetchall()]
#                      ^
```

---

```
>>> rows = [('entry1',), ('entry2',), ('entry3',)]
>>> rows
[('entry1',), ('entry2',), ('entry3',)]
>>> rows = [entry for entry, in rows]
>>> rows
['entry1', 'entry2', 'entry3']
```